# Multiple level category drop-down from the WordPress dashboard

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, dropdown

Working with thousands of **Categories** in **WordPress**; **parent categories, child categories, grand child categories**. It is cumbersome trying to scroll through to select the desired category. It is either confusing or at times time consuming. I have been looking at the code. Is it possible to create a hierarchical where the child category is shown based on the previous selected parent child and the grandchild category is shown based on the previously selected child category: like a multi-step dropdown

```
<select>
   <option>Parent Category <option>
</select>
- Based on the selected parent category, the child categories are then displayed 
<select>
   <option>Child Category <option>
</select>
- And Based on the selected child category, the grandchild categories are then displayed 
<select>
   <option>Child Category <option>
</select>
```

.... And so on....

[image]

[image]

[image]